# Relation between vague convergence and weak convergence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

[image]

This is the Portemanteau Theorem.

[image]

And this is its corollary. I tried to prove that (i) implies (ii) in this corollary using the Portemanteau Theorem above. But I have kept failed... What is so frustrating here is that I can't think of any way to apply the Portemanteau Theorem to continuous functions with compact support...

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded and continuous.  We want to show $\int f\,d\mu_n \to \int f\,d\mu$.

Fix $\epsilon > 0$ and find $\phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous and compactly supported with $0 \le \phi \le 1$ and $\int \phi \,d\mu > 1-\epsilon$.  (Hint: Find a sequence of such functions that increase pointwise to 1, and use monotone convergence.)  It follows that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \int (1-\phi)\,d\mu_n \le \epsilon$.

Now write $\int f\,d\mu_n = \int \phi f \,d\mu_n + \int (1-\phi)f\,d\mu_n$.

Comment: thanks for the answer (not my question). I see that in choosing that $\phi$, the fact that $\mu$ is a probability measure was effectively used.
On the other hand, if $\mu$ is not a probability measure, the equivalence isn't true, e.g. $\delta_n \to 0$ vaguely, but not weakly. So, I wonder, what's the maximal set $V$(vector space?) of all measures where vague and weak convergence coincide? Assume $\mu_n, \mu \in V$.